# Does trigger works with order?

Tags: postgresql, websocket, database-trigger

I created trigger which working after every insert and for each row

My question is in case I’m having like 1000 records which inserts together or working with websocket. Does the trigger is working this way:
Insert,trigger,insert,trigger...
Or it could be this way:
Insert,insert,trigger,trigger...?

I mean if it’s possible that the trigger will get the wrong NEW record in case of two inserts at the same time?

Comment: There are two trigger types: `for each row` and `for each statement` _This specifies whether the trigger function should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger event, or just once per SQL statement. **If neither is specified, FOR EACH STATEMENT is the default.**_ [Read more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: @Abelisto thanks for the answer. I’m using for each row, my question is that in case I have 2 different inserts at the same time. Can the trigger get confuse with the “NEW” record?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether the trigger is `DEFERRED` or not. Only *constraint triggers* are deferrable.

A row level trigger that runs `AFTER` and is not deferred runs immediately after the row has been modified. A deferred trigger runs at the end of the transaction.

If one statement affects multiple rows, the trigger will run for each row, and each time the trigger knows quite well for which row it is running.